# Plugging in USB causes MCU to die

Tags: usb, esd

I have seen the below circuit at work. It has two supporting circuits on one PCB, each with its own ground.

The circuit with the micro-USB is tied to the MCU circuitry via L3, L4, and C30.

The MCU keeps blowing up. I first power on the MCU PCB with 12 V. I then connect a USB cable from my laptop's USB port to the micro USB connector on the PCB. When doing this, the MCU gets very hot, very quickly.

Why does the MCU pop when I plug in my USB?

Additional info:
The PSU used is the  RS-25-12 from Meanwell.

[image]

Comment: Why did you draw that blue line labeled "isolation" when there's no actual isolation? Also, are the grounds really not connected?

Comment: @JonathanS. I added that line because on the PCB, they had someone else to design, I saw a clear separation between the two ground pours and the thing that linked the pour was the L3 inductor. Hence I drew that line. The grounds are connected in the way I showed in the "schematic"

Comment: Try replacing L3 and L4 with shorts, and also connect pin 5 (GND) and pin 11 (shield) of the USB connector.

Comment: @JonathanS. can I ask how this will help and why do I have this issue?

Comment: Probably a voltage differential between the grounds of the two systems. You can't know for sure until you try it.

Comment: Your MCU's GND and your USB GND (pin-5, not the shield on pin-11) *must* be connected together.

Comment: Not enough details to answer. I bet this simplified schematic does not reflect the actual design and the errors it has. For example, from where does the 12V supply come from, details of the supply, and why does not the buck converter have no ground? And the USB shield is not supposed to be used for the only ground that carries the current.

Comment: @Justme " from where does the 12V supply come from". It comes from a Meanwell 12V DC 2A AC/DC converter. "why does not the buck converter have no ground". This was an oversite on my part, it should have been in there. " USB shield is not supposed to be used for the only ground that carries the current". Understood. Will try to join these two grounds. I will get more information on Monday and update this post. Is there anything else that looks obviously wrong that I can look for on Monday as well?

Comment: @JoeyB The actual schematics would be better, instead of a simplified version drawn from memory. Also, now we know the supply is a Meanwell 12V 2A AC adapter. But without knowing which model, we don't know the details of the exact model and we also don't know if it is connected to mains correctly, or if your computer is too. It is possible your power supplies are used in a way that there is tens of volts between two devices and it will kill ICs via data lines.

Comment: @Justme "The actual schematics would be better, instead of a simplified version drawn from memory", will provide this on Monday. "It is possible your power supplies are used in a way that there are tens of volts between two devices and it will kill ICs via data lines." The Meanwell is a RS-25-12. It is connected correctly. Live to Live, Neutral to Neutral, and Ground to Ground, from the plug to the PSU. Can you explain how the tens of volts would come about and what do you mean by the "two devices"?